# Level-Shifting not working in Instrumentation Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, level-shifting, instrumentation-amplifier, dc-offset

I want to shift the measured EMG input signal to the positive side to use ADC. I used the REF input of AD8421 to add an offset of **2.5V**. I simulated the circuit below from the [AD8421 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8421.pdf) on Multisim.

[image: circuit diagram]

The output is only amplified but not **level-shifted**. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Multisim circuit simulation]

Comment: I'm confused by the multiplicity of red and blue node labels. Like red and blue "Amp". I am also concerned by the distance these labels might have from the node to which they are supposedly attached. Is it possible that two, otherwise distinct, nodes have been accidentally joined by labeling? Or even if there are duplicate components, one hidden under the other?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I changed the line colour to blue from red so that the oscilloscope shows the signal in blue. The on-page connector and line label have the same name, which is automatically assigned by the multisim on making a connection. I checked and there are no duplicates.

Comment: I am not familiar with Multisim. If the scope has ac couplig capability, make sure it is set to dc coupling.

Comment: @RussellH This is the answer. I didn't know about the AC and DC coupling. After setting the oscilloscope to DC, the waveform is level-shifted. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Multisim. If the scope has ac coupling capability, make sure it is set to dc coupling.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your input meets the common mode range requirement of the INA.

Please use this [diamond plot tool](https://tools.analog.com/en/diamond/#difL=-0.1&difR=0.1&difSl=-0.1&gain=10&l=0&pr=AD8421&r=0&sl=0&tab=1&ty=2&vn=-12&vp=12&vr=2.5) to verify the range.

Below simulation shows that circuit connections are perfect. Only culprit is the common mode range.

[image: Circuit daiagram]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have more success with an actual circuit on a breadboard than whatever MultiSim is doing. Simulation is a skill in its own. The circuit you've drawn will work if someone were to assemble it basing on the schematic diagram. MultiSim is not reading the diagram the same way you are, for some reason - I'm sure a MultiSim aficionado can chime in with juicy details about what little thing you got wrong.

EMG data acquisition works best with a differential electrode setup. That's why you'd be using an in-amp. As shown, you're using the in-amp to measure in single-ended configuration, and for that a cheaper op-amp will summarily beat the in-amp in every aspect of performance.

All you seem to want is a x10 single-ended input. A couple op-amps is all you need, and no need for a bipolar power supply either. Never mind that +/-12V in-amp supply for an EMG preamp is overkill. That in-amp would be running quite hot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTSy5n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit shown above has gain of 10, 1MΩ input impedance, 2.5V output reference level. The TLC2272's input common mode is 0V to 3.5V with 5V supply. The circuit is configured for common mode of 0.25V on the first stage, and 1.3V on the second stage. The gain is split into 5x on the 1st stage, and 2x on the second stage, to keep the common mode voltages in the input range of the op-amps. The op-amps have rail-to-rail outputs.

Amything for electrophysiology will need to be fully isolated, so there's no concern for where a "ground" is. The circuit can be easily made high-impedance just by moving the reference electrode to a potential above 0V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBkP3C.png)</sup>

Comment: Multisim is weird it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Your input regarding supply voltage and amplifier is valid. The original circuit I made on multisim for EMG works on 3.3 supply voltage and has a gain of 1000. But the level-shifting functionality wasn't working. To see what I am doing wrong, I just followed the circuit model from the datasheet. Will try in other simulators and check the output.

Comment: @Keestu Do you really need a gain of 1000? Many recent ADCs will almost take EMG straight from the leads with just an impedance buffer. With a gain of 10..100, you should be pretty much set with a 24-bit ADC. The circuit you show has a gain of 10, and so does the Multisim circuit. You will be very much disappointed in how a real circuit performs unless you ditch simulation and start putting real hardware together. It's all the things that simulation doesn't capture that will have most impact on the results, including construction technique, shielding, guarding, lead construction (yes!), etc.

Comment: Now that I think of it, EMG is just about the perfect signal for high-resolution audio ADC capture. Add a bit of gain, send it to an isolated, decent 32-bit audio capture device and you should be done. Let the sigma-delta ADC resolution and linearity do the hard work instead of high front-end gain.

Comment: Instead of suggesting a single-sided approach, wouldn't the asker be better off using an IA correctly for high CMRR?